# Using upload images in xp:inputRichText with a passed datasource did not work

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

i got an error with the upload image function in the ckeditor in XPages when i try to use a passed datasource in a custom control as the datasource for the richtext editor

[image]

In my main xpages i got this simple code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">

    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument
            var="document1"
            formName="test">
        </xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>

    <xc:cctest doc="#{javascript:document1}"></xc:cctest> 

</xp:view>
```

And in my custom control cctest i got just this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:inputRichText
        id="inputRichText1"
        value="#{compositeData.doc.body}">
    </xp:inputRichText>

</xp:view>
```

This is how the properties of the custom control cctest looks

[image]

When i you a datasource that is not passed to the custom control it works like a charm. Is this a general problem?

**UPDATE**

I tried the solution from Paul and it work's. Thanks for that.
But now i run into another problem.

I have to compute the fieldname in the custom control like

```
<xp:inputRichText
   id="inputRichText1"
   value="#{document1[compositeData.fieldName]}">
</xp:inputRichText>
```

Everything works, so i can save values in the field, but again, the inline image function in the editor stops working. Is there also a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The best advice I would give is don't pass the datasource, unless you absolutely have to. Because the Custom Control is at the same level of XML hierarchy or lower, it has access to the `document1` DominoDocument datasource variable you define on the XPage. So you don't necessarily need to pass it.

If your Custom Control uses the `document1` variable it will navigate upwards and outwards in the hierarchy (the "component tree") to find the first variable that has that name. So unless you have another `document1` variable (a dataContext or other datasource, most typically a DominoDocument datasource) "nearer" in the hierarchy, you're fine.

You won't get support in the Custom Control to allow you to select fields, because the Custom Control doesn't have the context of the final component tree that would be provided when the relevant XPage gets loaded by the browser. But apart from that it will work and removes the risk of someone using a Save All Datasources simple action (which will cause conflicts, because it will save all **instances** of that datasource) or a Save Datasource simple action at the wrong level (which might result in saving only some fields, I'm not sure, depending on whether XPages considers the two DominoDocument datasources are the same object or two different objects pointing to the same backend Document).

Comment: Thanks for the help...but i run into another problem. I update the question.

Comment: Try using "${..." instead of "#{...". The former will compute on page load, whereas the latter will compute dynamically. Bear in mind images have to be uploaded to a temp area and a "cid" reference added to the MIME content of the rich text field in order to display. That may not work dynamically.
The variable being passed as compositeData.fieldName will also need computing on page load rather than dynamically in order to be able to do this.

Comment: Arrr... when i use ${ instead of #{ than i will get an error Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.sun.faces.el.VariableResolverImpl.resolveVariable(VariableResolverImpl.java:65)